# How to use JS callbacks?

Tags: javascript, callback

I have some really hard times understanding JS callbacks. From what I understand is that JS callback is a function that takes the argument of another function. So let's say I have a function called myFunction and passes mySecond to it, will it exicute myFunction before mySecond?

```
function myFunction(){
alert("hello");
}
function mySecond(){
alert("world");}
}
myFunction(mySecond);
```

Comment: They can be tricky to wrap your head around at first. It’s just another parameter. You aren’t even using that parameter inside “myFunction”, so you will only see one alert.

Comment: I think I am using mySecond in the myFunction.

Comment: This example might help a bit: `function myFunction() { return 5 }; function mySecond(fn) { alert(2 + fn()); }; mySecond(myFunction);` Will alert 7. You pass one function as an argument to the other function and then you are able to call it in that other function.

Answer (score 0):

if you want myFunction before mySecond. The code is below.

```js
function myFunction(func){
  alert("hello");
  func();
}
function mySecond(){
  alert("world");}
}
myFunction(mySecond);
```

Hello, if you want myFunction after mySecond. The code is below.

```js
function myFunction(func){
  func();
  alert("hello");
}
function mySecond(){
  alert("world");}
}
myFunction(mySecond);
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: mySecond is a function. The name of `mySecond` is a reference. If you want mySecond run, you need invode it by `mySecond()`

Comment: What does the myfunc do inside the myFunction argument?

Answer (score 0):

> a JS callback is a function that takes the argument of another function

This "understanding" is confused and has it backwards:

- a JS [callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) is a function provided as an argument to another function, to be called back after the called function has done something.

---

A classic example or  callback function is provided by the syntax of `setTimeout`:

```
 setTimeout( callback, 1000);
```

Here `callback` (a function) is called back (by `setTimeout`) after a second has elapsed.